# phpstorm 8.0.3 xdebug 2.3+

Tags: profiling, phpstorm, xdebug

Is there profiling support for xdebug 2.3+ with phpstorm 8.0.3?

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="</home/karborator/tmp/profiling>"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

Nothing happens when I trying to start profiling with Chrome extension xdebug helper.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Profiling+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm+and+Xdebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if configured correctly, you should get a cachegrind file in xdebug.profiler_output_dir after the request has been profiled.

That's pretty much the whole profiling integration that PHPStorm currently supports. **You cannot visualize the data stored in this file using PhpStorm.**

On a Linux system you could use [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to view&analyze the outputed profiling report.